# how do i disable inactive scroll bar, but not permanently?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have two scroll bar on a page, one is active and another one is working in the background.

I want to disable that scroll bar till my first scroll bar working.

Comment: What do you mean by "working in the background"?

Answer (score 0):

That's pretty simple actually, have a look at the following code snippet:

```js
$(window).on("load",function(){
  $("#left").on("scroll",function() {
    $("#right").css("overflow","scroll"); //enable scrollbar
    $("#right").css("overflow-x","hidden"); //disable horizontal scrollbar
    $("#left").off("scroll"); //remove the scroll-handler
  });
});
```

```css
html, body {width:95%; height:95%;}

#left,#right {
  width: 45%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 2px solid grey;
}
#left {
  float: left;
  overflow: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
#right {
  float: right;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="left">
  This<br />is<br />a<br />line<br />This<br />is<br />a<br />line<br />This<br />is<br />a<br />line<br />This<br />is<br />a<br />line<br />This<br />is<br />a<br />line<br />This<br />is<br />a<br />line<br />This<br />is<br />a<br />line<br />This<br />is<br />a<br />line<br />This<br />is<br />a<br />line<br />This<br />is<br />a<br />line<br />This<br />is<br />a<br />line<br />This<br />is<br />a<br />line<br />This<br />is<br />a<br />line<br />This<br />is<br />a<br />line<br />This<br />is<br />a<br />line<br />This<br />is<br />a<br />line<br />This<br />is<br />a<br />line<br />This<br />is<br />a<br />line<br />This<br />is<br />a<br />line<br />This<br />is<br />a<br />line<br />This<br />is<br />a<br />line<br />This<br />is<br />a<br />line<br />This<br />is<br />a<br />line<br />This<br />is<br />a<br />line<br />This<br />is<br />a<br />line<br />This<br />is<br />a<br />line<br />This<br />is<br />a<br />line<br />
</div>

<div id="right">
  This<br />is<br />a<br />line<br />This<br />is<br />a<br />line<br />This<br />is<br />a<br />line<br />This<br />is<br />a<br />line<br />This<br />is<br />a<br />line<br />This<br />is<br />a<br />line<br />This<br />is<br />a<br />line<br />This<br />is<br />a<br />line<br />This<br />is<br />a<br />line<br />This<br />is<br />a<br />line<br />This<br />is<br />a<br />line<br />This<br />is<br />a<br />line<br />This<br />is<br />a<br />line<br />This<br />is<br />a<br />line<br />This<br />is<br />a<br />line<br />This<br />is<br />a<br />line<br />This<br />is<br />a<br />line<br />This<br />is<br />a<br />line<br />This<br />is<br />a<br />line<br />This<br />is<br />a<br />line<br />This<br />is<br />a<br />line<br />This<br />is<br />a<br />line<br />This<br />is<br />a<br />line<br />This<br />is<br />a<br />line<br />This<br />is<br />a<br />line<br />This<br />is<br />a<br />line<br />This<br />is<br />a<br />line<br />
</div>
```

(**fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dyedkj56/2/**)

- To disable the scrollbar, you put `overflow:hidden;` in the CSS for the second scrollbar.
- Then to enable it when the first scrollbar is scrolled, use the jQuery handler `.on("scroll",function(){`.
- Finally, to make sure this handler isn't needlessly called and executed every time you scroll after that first time, remove the handler with `.off("scroll")`.